# span with img as bg

Tags: image, html

Just curious, why can't I have/see my bg img on this span, unless I use position: absolute?! Is it because span is an inline element?

```
.thumb {
    background: url("images/yts.png") no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}

<span class="thumb"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The problem is that with inline elements, the width property has no effect. So a span with no content has a width of 0, and then only zero pixels of the background are visible!
You can use display:inline-block to resolve this, and there's no need to position it absolutely.